# Top Speed of Radeon RX 480 8GB

Tags: mining, mining-pools, windows

I'm mining in ethpool with windows 7 (intel i7 @ 2.80GHz 16GB....but that doesnt really matter, right?) and a Radeon RX 480 8GB card. humming along at a steady 24.75 mh/s. haven't done a thing to the settings. can i get better mh/s out of this setup by tweaking it a little bit? any input appreciated. cheers

Comment: I am currently running on ethos and only getting 23 mh/s max. Wondering the same thing you are.

Comment: yea i'm trying to maximize this thing to the fullest (without frying it). have u tweaked your speeds at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hashrate seems par for the course. At this point in the game, the mining software you are using is optimized to the fullest extent.

The only thing you can do now is try overclocking your card.  The core clock won't affect your hashrate much, but raising the memory clock may give you a boost.

I would start playing around with that value and determine what your card can run at stably.  If you go too high, your card may fail immediately or may work at first but fail in a few minutes/hours. Keep lowering the overclock until the card can run indefinitely without failure.

Comment: great....thanks for the input. any idea what might be a good speed to start off with? looks like its currently running at 1342 mhz and memory at 2000....whats a good increment to give a first try with? appreciate your help. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use MSI burner to overclock the memory. I got 27 mh/s

Many says they can get 30 Mh/s and lower power consumption by updating bios. However I have no luck doing so.

See [Why I got lower Hash Rate in Mining Ethereum after I use Someone Else BIOS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/why-i-got-lower-hash-rate-in-mining-ethereum-after-i-use-someone-else-bios) as I keep doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been consistently hitting 31.5MHs for months. [image]

Answer (score -2):

Seems like driver problem. My Asus rx 480 used to get very low speed due to use of very recent driver (non supported)

Now using 16.12.2 and found everything alright.

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: i just hooked up a 4th monitor to my computer (need them all for work) and it brought me down to 20 MH/s (from a steady 25). i hooked it up to hdmi port on my system (not the card) and it definitely decreased the speed by 5 MH/s. anyone have any suggestions as to how to get it back up to speed (pun intended)...using driver version 9.14.10.01249. any known issues with that version?